# Multiple for-of loops, in the same statement(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

From mozillas js docs:

```
for (variable of iterable) {
    statement
 }
```

This is the standard for of statement in js and I want to do something like this:

```
for (variable of iterable && variable of iterable) {
   statement
}
```

I just need the loops to not iterate and then iterate again for each nested for of loop. So something that is similar would be great for my needs but the above seems preferable.

I have 2 arrays that I am trying to iterate through and would like to create objects and check for their equality(or something else) further down.

Example scenario:

```
for (variable1 of iterable1 && variable2 of iterable2) {
   //code
  if (variable1 === variable2){
   //do something
  }
}
```

my code:

```
 if (_.intersection(selections[i],questions[i].correctAnswer)) {
       for (const selection of selections[i]) for (const answer of questions[i].correctAnswer) for(const item of questions[i].qPoints) {
          if (selection === answer){

        numCorrect += item;

        console.log(numCorrect)
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Basically what I am doing with intersection is checking if the two arrays intersect using underscoreJS. After that, I am trying to create objects for each of these arrays. Firstly, to check whether or not arrays are equal at any point, and if so incrementing numCorrect by the value of the correctanswer at that index(qPoints). The issue is with nested for loops, I am getting the value of qPoints by some multiple(due to excessive iterations).

Comment: What do your iterables look like?

Comment: They are just arrays of integer values or ints as strings

Comment: What?  Are you trying to compare the nth element of iterable1 with every element in iterable2, or just the nth of iterable1 with the nth of iterable2?

Comment: If you are working with arrays then forEach or map might be more suited to your needs e.g. iterable1.forEach( function (itemFrom1, i) { var itemFrom2 = iterable2[i]})

Comment: @James nth of Iterable1 to nth of Iterable2

Comment: check my update @riemannsolve

Comment: Is the structure that the selections array is just a list of integers, and the questions array is just a list of objects with a correctAnswer number property and a qPoints number property? And the indexes of the two arrays correspond to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just edit your code to be =>

```
let correctAnswer = questions[i].correctAnswer; 

let qPoints = questions[i].qPoints;

if (_.intersection(selections[i],questions[i].correctAnswer)) {
   selections[i].forEach((selection, index) => {
     if (selection === correctAnswer[index]) {
       numCorrect += qPoints[index];
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use 'for' - you can access the underlying Iterator directly.

```
i1 = iterable1.iterator; i2 = iterable2.iterator;
while (!i1.done && !i2.done) {
    variable1 = i1.next; variable2 = i2.next;

    ... do something with the pair
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of object or shape you got but if your objects are arrays for example, then just loop over one of them and compare by its index to the other array.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,10,25,45];
const arr2 = [3,5,8,7,5,10,25,84,98,71,1];

arr1.forEach((o,i) => {
  console.log(o,arr2[i],o == arr2[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why does something like this not work:

```
for (var x = 0; x < selections.length && x < questions.length; x++) {
    var selection = selections[x];
    var question = questions[x];
    if (selection === question.correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect += question.qPoints;
    }
}
```